# meta: is this the right forum to ask about Chrome behavior?

Tags: discussion

Meta question: Is it the right place for such questions? or there is a different Stack Exchange forum that is more suitable than 'superuser'?

Comment: Side note: you can browse the existing [tag:google-chrome] questions on SU and ask if it's not a duplicate.

Comment: Stack Exchange / Super User is not a forum. :)

Answer (score 4):

As long as it is the desktop version of Chrome, as in Windows, Linux or macOS, then [Superuser](https://superuser.com/) is the right place to ask.

For the Android version there is [Android Enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/).